# How to modify this Regex for ASP.NET to restrict year to YYYY (MM/-dd/-yyyy)

Tags: asp.net, regex

I copied this from RegEx Library to validate input date. It works fine except that it allows yy as well as yyyy. But the SQL Server rejects date with yy. So i want to restrict this RegEx to only accept yyyy. How do i change this to accept yyyy and not yy ?

```
^(((((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|([12]\d)|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|([12]\d)|(30)))|((0?2)[\.\-/]?((0?[1-9])|(1\d)|(2[0-8]))))[\.\-/]?(((19)|(20))?([\d][\d]))))|((0?2)[\.\-/]?(29)[\.\-/]?(((19)|(20))?(([02468][048])|([13579][26])))))$"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `?`s after `((19)|(20))` to make those groups non-optional.

That said, do you really trust that regex? My eyes are glazing over from all those unnecessary parentheses, brackets and backslashes - if terseness of syntax is any indication, my guess is that whoever wrote this doesn't know too much about regexes.

Comment: how did you figure out that fast, i was still struggling with the first alternative in the regex :p

Comment: @aelor: I scanned the regex for `19` and `20`. I didn't even try to understand the rest of it. Date validation regexes are a nightmare.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Do you have a better idea ? Is it better to just check for CustomValidation or Regular Expression validation for dates in ASPNET ?

Comment: @Chakra: Couldn't you just do a basic sanity check in regex `\d\d[/-]\d\d[/-]\d{4}` and then use `Datetime.ParseExact()` to check if it's valid (and falls into the allowed range etc.)?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes that is what i did and will test it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the below regex to validate the `MM/-dd/-yyyy`

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\.\-/]?(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])[\.\-/](19|20)\d{2}$
```